# How to handle errors in an rest api batch operation?

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, error-handling

I want my API to do a batch operation. In this case it should create multiple.
One issue I stumbled upon is how to handle errors in this case.

Here is a rundown of what happens:

Client makes a post request with a list of entities.
The api takes those entities and validates the fields and relations of those entities.
If one or more errors occur (for example if a reference isnt found in the DB) the operation is cancelled and rolled back.

How do I handle this?
I know there is a http status for multistatus. Do I use this?
What error code would I use for a entity that could be created but wasnt because another entity failed?
What is the best practice here?

I tried googling for this case but couldnt really find an answer. There are some blogs about handling errors but none if the ones I found was talking specifically about my issue.

In case its important: I am using spring boot 2.7 with kotlin

Answer (score 1):

> How do I handle this? I know there is a http status for multistatus. Do I use this? What error code would I use for a entity that could be created but wasnt because another entity failed? What is the best practice here?

All of the fine grained details of the error that you want to report to the client belong in the response body.

The status code is meta data of the [transfer-of-documents-over-a-network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s) domain; it communicates to other general purpose HTTP response consumers the semantics of the response, so that they can take the appropriate intelligent actions.

I would discourage use of 207 Multistatus unless you are deliberately trying to create a WebDAV facade (See [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918.html) etc.)

Since the failure is related to the list of entities in the request, we should normally be using one of the [registered 4xx client](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) errors.

I would normally start with [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-403-forbidden) (the server understood what was being asked, but chooses not to do it, because reasons).

Alternatives to consider would be [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-400-bad-request) (not my preference because it's ambiguous about whether the server understood the request), [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-409-conflict) (not necessarily unreasonable, especially if there is a way for the client to fix things), [422 Unprocessable Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-422-unprocessable-content) (not my preference here because the semantics of the payload are correct).

In practice, I think you'll find that any of these responses is *fine*, because general purpose HTTP components don't distinguish these codes from each other in any important ways.

So you might reasonably look to other considerations to make your choice - if we use a distinct code here, does that make life easier for humans you care about?  For instance, your operators might prefer that you use a different error message semantics for this case than you would use for forbidden access, because monitoring.  And that's *fine*.